# How to suppress words in a DIV

Tags: html

How can i suppress words in a DIV (which has a defined width and height) in a way that is shown in the picture below without messing with the order?

[image]

If there is no luck doing that in a DIV, what should i do to sort this out?

Comment: I don't understand your question. In your example, no word is suppressed, there's only a different layout. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to put max. 6 elements for each line. The list might get bigger dynamically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `column-count` here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/X3XtK/1/

Saw your comment now. If you need to limit each column to a maximum of 6 items and there's an unknown amount of items then `column-count` will be tricky. I think you'll have to group them in the markup (putting each group of 6 in their own `div` and then floating them for example).

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a small jQuery script. See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GlauberRocha/ZwY7q/

I've made it as a list instead as a `div` (but you can easily modify this). In my example, the items are initially in an unordered list (`ul`). They are recursively taken out 6 by 6 and put in a new ordered list (`ol`) element, which is floated.

It's fine if you can group your elements in the original markup (as suggested by @powerbuoy), but doing it with JavaScript has two advantages:

- You keep your HTML markup simple and "semantic",
- The number of rows can be set dynamically (in my example, it's passed as an argument to the function)